# android 5.1 capitve portal on open wrt - redirect does not work due to browser cache?

Tags: android, ios, openwrt

I am running a captive portal based on open wrt with nodogsplash. Since the new Android 5 update there is the following problem:

New android devices (5.0 and 5.1) that have already visited the network before, are not redirected to the captive portal login page. http requests are returned in a normal way. The webpages load even though the devices are not authenticated yet and should not be able to access any websites. https requests shows a network error. all other connections for apps etc... are denied on the phone.

Only when opening the incognito browser or delete all browser data, a normal http requests is forwarded to the captive portal login page where the user can authenticate and then receive full access to the network.

Older android devices, ios devices and laptops do not experience the same problem. here everything seems normal.

Did anyone come across something similar? This is a big security problem for our network.

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my problem ;-)

The google chrome option "data saver" routes some traffic though google servers and therefore prevents the redirect to the captive portal login page. This is of course a major pain in the ass and I do not have a solution to work around this.

But at least I know now in what direction to look.

If anyone has an Idea - it would be greatly appreciated.